# Display the values in Datatable with Two decimal places to looks like time Format

Tags: c#

I have to display the values in DataTable with Exactly Two Decimal places. 
I want to display like this to looks like a time format.
(I apologize for my English)
thank you.

```
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("SOT", typeof(Decimal));
        dt.Columns.Add("SVT", typeof(Decimal));
        dt.Columns.Add("SCT", typeof(Decimal));
        dt.Rows.Add(12.22,23.44,22.00);
        dt.Rows.Add(2.20, 23.00, 22.23);
        dt.Rows.Add(12.00, 23.20, 22.05);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception d)
    {
        Response.Write(d.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

DataTable Can take values like (2.2,23,22.5) not (2.20,23.00,22.5).
Is there any method to insert values in DataTable like (2.20,23.00,22.5)

Comment: As a "time" format? Please explain what you mean by that. To show a floating point value with two decimal digits you can use `d.ToString(".00")`

Comment: See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ShortTime

Comment: And also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: To displaying a value with two decimal places will looks like time format. That' what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
decimal a = 5;
decimal b = 6;

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:#,###.00}, {1:#,###.00}", a , b));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the String.Format methods.
You can use the following:

```
string.Format("{0:f2}", YourDecimalValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

This, perhaps?:

```
Value.ToString(".00")
```